# Tkinter window crashes when clicked, probably due to infinite loop. Python 3.7.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a programm that reads ANT signals and displays them in a TKinter window.
To display the changing values, I'm updating labels (in an infinite loop),which works so far, but whenever I try to move the window, the program crashes (no response).
So here's what the (final program) should do:

- Receive and store the ANT data, which I read with another file (which gives me
  power and cadence)
- Round the numbers to 2-3 decimals (max)
- Read the total power output so far from a file
- Write the power data in a file (append)
- Sum the total power output
- display the current speed, cadence, power and total power output

My Code:

```
# imports
import random
import time
from tkinter import *

# creating root tkinter Window
root = Tk()
root.title("ANT+ Live Data")

# defining Text Variables
running = 0
SAVE_FILE = "power_doc.txt"
HEADLINE_TEXT = StringVar()
HEADLINE_TEXT.set('')
HEADLINE_M = StringVar()
HEADLINE_M.set('')
power_display = StringVar()
power_display.set('0')
cadence_display = StringVar()
cadence_display.set('0')
speed_display = StringVar()
speed_display.set('0')
powertotal_display = StringVar()
powertotal_display.set('0')

# defining Window Size
root.geometry("800x600")

# creating Label Frame to wrap labels
frame = LabelFrame(root)
frame.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

# creating labels, Headline 1
slabel = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",48) ,textvariable = HEADLINE_M, justify=CENTER, bg="#FFFFFF", fg = '#000000')
slabel.pack(fill=BOTH, padx=20, pady=10)

# headline 2
headLine = Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 26), textvariable= HEADLINE_TEXT, justify=CENTER, bg="#FFFFFF", fg = '#000000')
headLine.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=5)

# power
l1 = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",20) ,textvariable = power_display, justify=CENTER, bg="#190000", fg = '#B0C4C2')
l1.pack(fill=BOTH)

# cadence
l2 = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",20), textvariable = cadence_display, justify=CENTER, bg="#190000", fg = '#B0C4C2')
l2.pack(fill=BOTH)

# speed
l3 = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",20), textvariable = speed_display, justify=CENTER, bg="#190000", fg = '#B0C4C2')
l3.pack(fill=BOTH)

# total Power
l4 = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",20), textvariable = powertotal_display, justify=CENTER, bg="#190000", fg = '#B0C4C2')
l4.pack(fill=BOTH)


# function to read total power values out of a file
def get_power_total(SAVE_FILE):
    power_total = 0
    with open(SAVE_FILE, 'r') as inp:
        for line in inp:
            try:
                num = float(line)
                power_total += num
            except ValueError:
                print('{} is not a number!'.format(line))
    power_total = round_number(power_total)
    return power_total


# generate random Numbers for testing purposes
def randomize_number(inputNumber):
    inputNumber = float(inputNumber)*random.uniform(0.99, 1.01)
    inputNumber = round_number(inputNumber)
    return inputNumber


# rounds numbers to 2 decimals
def round_number(inputNumber):
    inputNumber = round(inputNumber, 2)
    return inputNumber


# use formula for a 28" Wheel to determine Speed using cadence
def determine_speed(cadence):
    speed = float(cadence)*0.356
    speed = round_number(speed)
    return speed


def get_power(cadence):
    power = float(cadence)*0.8
    power = round_number(power)
    return power


# dummy function to test-print Values, redundant in current state
def print_values(x1, x2, x3):
    print("Leistung: {} W Trittfrequenz: {} Geschwindigkeit: {} Km/H" .format(x1, x2, x3))


# write in document to determine total power output
def write_file(SAVE_FILE, power):
    f = open(SAVE_FILE, "a+")
    f.write(str(power) + '\n')
    f.close()


def update_label():
    power_total = get_power_total(SAVE_FILE)
    cadence = int(50)
    cadence = randomize_number(cadence)
    root.after(100)
    power = get_power(cadence)
    root.after(100)
    speed = determine_speed(cadence)
    root.after(100)
    power_total += power
    write_file(SAVE_FILE, power)
    power_display.set("Leistung: {} W".format(power))
    cadence_display.set("Trittfrequenz: {}".format(cadence))
    speed_display.set("Geschwindigkeit : {} Km/h".format(speed))
    powertotal_display.set("Gesamtleistung seit 10 Uhr: {} W".format(power_total))
    root.after(1000)
    root.update_idletasks()


# mainloop to display the window
while True:

        root.after(1000, update_label())

root.mainloop()
```

This is basically just a draft to import the ANT data, hence there are some numbers being randomly generated to show if the label update function works.
I'm fairly new to coding with Python (or coding at all), so I'm pretty sure there are other issues with my code as well, but perhaps someone has a suggestion on how to solve my issue.
Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Cheers in advance!

Edit: Solved! thanks Jason!

Changes were to be made here:

```
def update_label():
    power_display.set("Leistung: {} W".format(power))
    cadence_display.set("Trittfrequenz: {}".format(cadence))
    speed_display.set("Geschwindigkeit : {} Km/h".format(speed))
    powertotal_display.set("Gesamtleistung seit 10 Uhr: {} W".format(power_total))
    root.after(1000, update_label)
    root.update_idletasks()

root.after(1000, update_label)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What that `while` loop does is to call `update_label()` *right now* an infinite number of times, and for each one schedule *absolutely nothing* (the return value of the function) to happen one second later.  You don't need a loop at all - just put `root.after(1000, update_label)` (note lack of `()`!) both at the bottom of your code, and at the bottom of `update_label()` so that it reschedules itself whenever it is called.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you so, so much! That solved it! I've tried it with update_label at the end of my code, but that didn't help at all. I didn't know that I'd have to put update_label in my update_label() method.