# Python 3.7.1 ANT+ TKinter - displaying live data from an ANT+ Device in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sensors

Related to my question as of yesterday ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53726359/tkinter-window-crashes-when-clicked-probably-due-to-infinite-loop-python-3-7-1)), I tried to implement this [python-ant repository](https://github.com/bissont/python-ant) with the fork created by [Bissont](https://github.com/bissont). I've tried utilizing his power demo for the tacx bushido smart trainer, as this is the same device I use.
I've slightly altered the code to fit my Suunto ANT+ receiver, and running it in the console, the code worked. Now I've tried to implement it in a TKinter environment to display live data received from the ANT+ device, but end up with the following error code and the Tkinter Window doesn't open anymore:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ant-0.1.1-py3.5.egg/ant/core/node.py",
>   line 212, in start
>       self.reset(wait)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ant-0.1.1-py3.5.egg/ant/core/node.py",
>   line 197, in reset
>       evm.waitForMessage(message.StartupMessage)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ant-0.1.1-py3.5.egg/ant/core/event.py",
>   line 163, in waitForMessage
>       return self.msg.waitFor(class_, timeout)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ant-0.1.1-py3.5.egg/ant/core/event.py",
>   line 114, in waitFor
>       raise MessageTimeoutError("%s: timeout" % str(foo), internal=foo) ant.core.exceptions.MessageTimeoutError: : timeout
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/python-ant/demos/ant.core/ANT+ power.py", line 47, in
>   
>       antnode.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ant-0.1.1-py3.5.egg/ant/core/node.py",
>   line 217, in start
>       raise NodeError(err) ant.core.exceptions.NodeError: : timeout

So here's what the (final program) should do:

- Receive and store the ANT data
- Round the numbers to 2-3 decimals (max)
- Read the total power output so far from a file
- Write the power datain a file (append)
- Sum the total power output
- display the current speed, cadence, power and total power output

Here's my code so far:

```
# imports
import random
import time
from tkinter import *

from ant.core import driver
from ant.core.node import Node, Network, ChannelID
from ant.core.constants import NETWORK_KEY_ANT_PLUS, NETWORK_NUMBER_PUBLIC
from ant.plus.power import *

from config import *

# creating root tkinter Window
root = Tk()
root.title("TacX Bushido ANT+ Live Data")

# defining text variables
running = 0
SAVE_FILE = "power_doc.txt"
HEADLINE_TEXT = StringVar()
HEADLINE_TEXT.set('Headline')
HEADLINE_M= StringVar()
HEADLINE_M.set('M')
power_display = StringVar()
power_display.set('0')
cadence_display = StringVar()
cadence_display.set('0')
speed_display = StringVar()
speed_display.set('0')
powertotal_display = StringVar()
powertotal_display.set('0')

# defining ANT variables
device = driver.USB2Driver(log=LOG, debug=DEBUG, idProduct=0x1008)
antnode = Node(device)
antnode.start()
network = Network(key=NETWORK_KEY_ANT_PLUS, name='N:ANT+')
antnode.setNetworkKey(NETWORK_NUMBER_PUBLIC, network)



# defining Window Size
root.geometry("800x600")

# creating Label Frame to wrap labels
frame = LabelFrame(root)
frame.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

# creating labels, Headline 1
Mlabel = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",48) ,textvariable = HEADLINE_M, justify=CENTER, bg="#FFFFFF", fg = '#000000')
Mlabel.pack(fill=BOTH, padx=20, pady=10)

# headline 2
headLine = Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 26), textvariable= HEADLINE_TEXT, justify=CENTER, bg="#FFFFFF", fg = '#000000')
headLine.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=5)

# power
l1 = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",20) ,textvariable = power_display, justify=CENTER, bg="#190000", fg = '#B0C4C2')
l1.pack(fill=BOTH)

# cadence
l2 = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",20), textvariable = cadence_display, justify=CENTER, bg="#190000", fg = '#B0C4C2')
l2.pack(fill=BOTH)

# speed
l3 = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",20), textvariable = speed_display, justify=CENTER, bg="#190000", fg = '#B0C4C2')
l3.pack(fill=BOTH)

# total Power
l4 = Label(root, font = ("Helvetica",20), textvariable = powertotal_display, justify=CENTER, bg="#190000", fg = '#B0C4C2')
l4.pack(fill=BOTH)


# function to read total power values out of a file
def get_power_total(SAVE_FILE):
    power_total = 0
    with open(SAVE_FILE, 'r') as inp:
        for line in inp:
            try:
                num = float(line)
                power_total += num
            except ValueError:
                print('{} is not a number!'.format(line))
    power_total = round_number(power_total)
    return power_total

# rounds numbers to 2 decimals
def round_number(inputNumber):
    inputNumber = round(inputNumber, 2)
    return inputNumber


# use formula for a 28" Wheel to determine Speed using cadence
def determine_speed(cadence):
    speed = float(cadence)*0.356
    speed = round_number(speed)
    return speed


# write in document to determine total power output
def write_file(SAVE_FILE, power):
    f = open(SAVE_FILE, "a+")
    f.write(str(power) + '\n')
    f.close()

# updates label
def update_label(power, cadence):
    power_total = get_power_total(SAVE_FILE)
    speed = determine_speed(cadence)
    power_total += power
    write_file(SAVE_FILE, power)
    power_display.set("Power: {} W".format(power))
    cadence_display.set("Cadence: {}".format(cadence))
    speed_display.set("Speed : {} Km/h".format(speed))
    powertotal_display.set("Total Power Output: {} W".format(power_total))
    root.after(1000, power_data)
    root.update_idletasks()

# find device
def device_found(self, device_number, transmission_type):
    print("Detect monitor device number: %d, transmission type: %d" % (device_number, transmission_type))

# determine power
def power_data(eventCount, pedalDiff, pedalPowerRatio, cadence, accumPower, instantPower):
    update_label(instantPower, cadence)

power  = BicyclePower(antnode, network, callbacks = {'onDevicePaired': device_found,
                                              'onPowerData': power_data})

# Unpaired, search:
power.open()


monitor = None
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

power.close()
antnode.stop()
# mainloop to display the window
root.after(1000, power_data)
root.mainloop()
```

I already know that the the while True statement will block my Tkinter Window from opening until a device has been found, which is subpar, but I didn't come up with a better approach as to leave it as it was.

Any suggestions, help or whatever is highly appreciated.

Cheers in advance!

Edit (for anyone that is interested or stuck in the same topic):
After examining the library further, I figured that power.open() creates an infinite loop of callbacks, which leads to the root.mainloop() to never be reached. I am yet to find a way to interfere in the callback loop to grab data, display it in the mainloop and proceed with the callback loop.
I'll try to provide more info and a possible solution once I've found it.
Feel free to contribute if you have an idea or a different approach to this :)

Edit 2:
Since the ANT+ module reads and writes data per se, one approach may be to write in a file and have another script read the data from the file. However, I do not know if that is possible in python (something like readonly-mode without blocking access from other sources).

Edit 3:
Problem solved:
Strip the script in 2 parts (seperate scripts).
1st Script:
Read ANT+ data and write it in a file like this:

```
def write_file(SAVE_FILE, power):
        f = open(SAVE_FILE, "w")
        f.write(str(power) + '\n')
        f.close()
```

2nd Script:
Read-only data and assign values, like this:

```
def readFile():
    file = open("ultimateFile.txt", "r")
    VALUE = file.readline()
    file.close()
    return VALUE
```

I will update the code/scripts in 2019 and upload the updated code/scripts to github.

Comment: I'm running similar code and getting errors from the "import ant.core" lines. What packages do you need to install in order to use ant.core modules?